# collection with addAttributeToSelect("*") still don't get all data!

Tags: magento-1.9, product, product-collection, stock

Lets say I do the following:

```
$prod = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$prod->load(243);
Mage::log($prod->getStockItem()->getIsInStock());
```

I get 1 (eg function returns true)

However, if I do this:

```
$productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
                            ->setPageSize($pageSize)->setCurPage($pageIndex)
                            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')->load();
```

then I iterate over the products and do

```
Mage::log($prod->->getStockItem()->getIsInStock());
```

I always get false, even for item 243 which should return true.

Why is that? and how do I load the stock item data?

(what I care about is if item is really in stock)

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want your collection to include the inventory information, there's a flag you need to set before you load the collection.

`$productCollection->setFlag('require_stock_items', true)`

Answer (score 2):

Product stock is a different table(`cataloginventory_stock_item`). Try this:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->joinField('qty', 'cataloginventory/stock_item', 'qty', 'product_id=entity_id', '{{table}}.stock_id=1', 'left')
    ->addAttributeToFilter(
        'qty', 
        array("gt" => 0)
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

Notice the double arrows ->-> after $prod

```
Mage::log($prod->->getStockItem()->getIsInStock());
```

---

You are probably thinking along the lines that a product should be loaded completely when it is part of the collection. It seems that it isn't. I think it's the whole EAV and storing data in different tables.

So you can use Richard's suggestion also loads the full stock_items

> $productCollection->setFlag('require_stock_items', true)

Or you can join the is_in_stock column to your product in the collection

```
$productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
                        ->setPageSize($pageSize)->setCurPage($pageIndex)
                        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                        ->joinField(
                            'is_in_stock',
                            'cataloginventory/stock_item',
                            'is_in_stock',
                            'product_id=entity_id',
                            '{{table}}.stock_id=1',
                            'left')
                        ->load();
```

Or join a table with the columns from stock data that you need.

```
 $productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
                            ->setPageSize($pageSize)->setCurPage($pageIndex)
                            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                            ->joinTable(
                                    'cataloginventory/stock_item',
                                    'product_id=entity_id',

                                    //columns needed
                                    array('stock_id','qty', 'min_qty', 'backorders', 'is_in_stock')
                            )
                            ->load();
```

If you need to see the columns of stock_item table, execute this query in your database

```
use database_name;
show columns from cataloginventory_stock_item;
```

---

A couple of debugging tips.
If you use ->load(true) at the end of the collection, you will get the SQL query that was executed.

You can also print all the data of a product by using getData()

```
// gets the first item of the collection and print its data
var_dump($productCollection->getFirstItem()->getData());
```

In your example, within the iteration:

```
Mage::log($prod->getData());
```

---

A bit off topic, if you are adding items to a Quote/Cart and you get the error below you can use Richard's suggestion when you load the collection.

> The stock item for Product is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*');

if($collection->getSize()) {
    foreach($collection as $product) {
        echo 'Product Name : '. $product->getName().'<br>';
        echo 'Product Stock : '. $product->getStockItem()->getIsInStock().'<br><br>';
    }           
}
```